# chrome extension storage api won't set array

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I am developing a Chrome extension and making use of the Storage API [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).
As far as I know I am able to store JS objects and arrays.

I have a piece of code:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(["fflist", "signature", "quote", "avatarHide", "ads", "tweet", "filters", "vine", "webm", "cats", "main", "tree", "embedTweet"],function (obj){
    g = obj;

   //all my functions and code are wrapped inside here, the rest of the options      
   //returned inside g are either primitives (booleans) and I have one object. 

    var t = g.fflist
    t.push(a[0])
    console.log(t)
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"fflist": t},function (){
    });
    console.log(g.fflist[0])
});
```

`a[0]` is some jQuery object that I know is not empty and is what I am wanting.`

Now, the output from `console.log(g.fflist[0])` shows that `g.fflist[0]` has the proper value I would like to store. Such as `<tr class="forum forum_268">..</tr>`

I then reload the page. And suddenly when I log the output of `console.log(g.fflist[0])` it just seems to be an empty object, `Object {}`
It doesnt make any sense why

UPDATE: Solution

I was being very silly thinking I could store DOM objects or jQuery objects in the storage cache. But with blunderboys comment combined with the following code to find the classes again;

```
    var geg = new RegExp("forum ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)")
    var g = geg.exec(thing)
    if (g!=null){
        $("#favouriteForums").after($("."+g[1]))
     }
```

Where `thing` is the class name attribute that I am storing in storage.

Since I can't store the changes to these elements and only reference to the originals, I will now need to reproduce the changes on the fly but it shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: You have to add code from here you are reading your `g` object

Comment: @blunderboy oops, there we go, thanks!

Comment: Can you please combine your code into one block Then I will answer your question.

Comment: @blunderboy is that better? I was trying to keep it as self contained as possible

Comment: Yeah much much better because it is more readable now and anybody can understand your code. Thanks for updating!!

Comment: I am not sure you can store reference to a DOM element(jQuery object) in local/sync storage. That does not make any sense.

Comment: @blunderboy from the reference I linked to, it states `User data can be stored as objects (the localStorage API stores data in strings).` And I have already stored an object (of booleans) with no ill effects. For some reason it's just this array that is being strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your post, you are trying to save a jQuery object in chrome storage area. You need to understand there is a difference between object, array and array-like objects.

jQuery object is just a wrapper over HTML DOM element and it is just a reference.

You might want to store the selector of the element in chrome storage area instead and get the element again by using that selector.

Here is how you can do that:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(["fflist", "signature", "embedTweet"],function (obj){
    g = obj;

   //all my functions and code are wrapped inside here, the rest of the options      
   //returned inside g are either primitives (booleans) and I have one object. 

    var t = g.fflist || [];
    // Add selector of a into t
    t.push('.my-class-selector'); //Selector is a string
    console.log(t);
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'fflist': t}, function (){ });
    console.log(g.fflist[0]);
});
```

To get the element back, you can use `$(g.fflist[0])`;

Comment: The only "problem" with this is that if I store the class name, such as `forum forum_268 `, then I can't actually retrieve it using that same string. `.forum forum_268` also does not find anything. Would I need to set up a small regex to ignore the `forum` part and just pick up the `forum_268` part? I realise it would need to be `.forum_268`

Comment: please see my updated question with the solution and I will accept this as the answer, thanks again

Comment: @user1079404 I am glad you could figure out the solution yourself after some hint :) Cheers!!